# Leaving one gameObject, deactivate others from an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array of gameObjects which I can deactivate easily with a loop. However I do not want to deactivate one gameObject from the lot. So I am providing an int value which is the position of the gameObject in that array. How do I deactivate others except for this particular object?

```
public GameObject[] myObjs;
int exceptionObj;

void Start()
{
  exceptionObj = 2; //Position of object in the array
  for(int i = 0; i<myObjs.Length; i++)
   {
     myObjs[i].SetActive(false);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
public GameObject[] myObjs;
int exceptionObj;

void Start()
{
  exceptionObj = 2; //Position of object in the array
  for(int i = 0; i<myObjs.Length; i++)
   {
     if(exceptionObj != i)
        myObjs[i].SetActive(false);
   }
}
```

Or;

```cs
public GameObject[] myObjs;
int exceptionObj;

void Start()
{
  exceptionObj = 2; //Position of object in the array
  for(int i = 0; i<myObjs.Length; i++)
   {
     if(exceptionObj == i)
        continue;

     myObjs[i].SetActive(false);
   }
}
```

Or perhaps even by simply reactivating at the end;

```cs
public GameObject[] myObjs;
int exceptionObj;

void Start()
{
  exceptionObj = 2; //Position of object in the array
  for(int i = 0; i<myObjs.Length; i++)
   {
     myObjs[i].SetActive(false);
   }
  myObjs[exceptionObj].SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: You can btw even shorten it more: `for(var int = 0; i < myObjs.Length; i++){ myObjs[i].SetActive(exceptionObj == i); }` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. With an if:

   ```
   exceptionObj = 2; //Position of object in the array
   for(int i = 0; i<myObjs.Length; i++)
   {
     if (i != exceptionObj) // If not the exception ID
         myObjs[i].SetActive(false);
   }
   ```
2. Or with two loops:

   ```
   exceptionObj = 2; //Position of object in the array
   for(int i = 0; i<exceptionObj; i++)
   {
      myObjs[i].SetActive(false);
   }
   for(int i = exceptionObj+1; i<myObjs.Length; i++)
   {
      myObjs[i].SetActive(false);
   }
   ```